# Message: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Too many links

Tags: filesystems, ext3, limits

We run a web application as a production. Some days ago I discovered the error signed in subject of this theme. I know what's the problem, but want to ask, what is right way for resolve this? Yes, we have ext3 FS on this server (CentOS 5.8).

```
find /var/www/html1 -type f | wc -l
36039
```

I think that converting ext3 -> ext4 will fix this situation temporary. Ext4 has this limit twice larger than ext3 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features ).

So, what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I converted that partition to ext4.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? is it necessary to reboot the computer after converting?

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting to modify this limit, the best way would be to create another folder ( /var/www/html2 ) and create symlinks between html1/sub1/ and html2/sub1/ ect...

Comment: Okay. What about ext4? Is there any way to modify its limit? Maybe different FS index or another.

Comment: There is a default limit of 64k without dir_nlink feature. When you create your FS make sure that dir_nlink is enable with mkfs.ext4.